# Code to add mouseover functionality to line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

Hi I'm trying to get the mouseover function work for my line chart so I can hover over the line chart and see the values of each point. I tried using the mouse function but it didn't work. How can I do this? I also included a picture of the line chart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Unemployment by Ward Bar Chart</title>

  <style type="text/css">
  .axis text{
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 13px;
  color: #333333;
  text-anchor: end;
 }

path { 
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
 stroke: grey;
stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}


.textlabel{
font-family:  Arial;
font-size:13px;
color: #333333;
text-anchor: middle;
}
}

 </style>
 <body>


 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

 <script>

 // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 60, left: 60},

 width = 475;
height = 350;
 padding = 100; 


   // Adds the svg canvas
   var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);




 // Parse the date / time
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y").parse;
  var formatTax = d3.format(",.2f");

 // Set the ranges
 var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width - margin.right - margin.left], .1)
.nice();


 var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 20])
.nice();

 // Define the axes
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function(d) {return "$" + d + "B"});



  // Define the line
 var valueline = d3.svg.line()

.x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(d["Tax Collections"]); });




  // Get the data
    d3.csv("Yearly Tax Collections.csv", function(error, data) {
   data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
   d["Tax Collections"] = formatTax(+d["Tax Collections"]/1000000000);
 });


  var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom); 

  // Scale the range of the data
 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));

 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.ceil (d["Tax   Collections"]); })
    ]);



   // Add the valueline path and mouseover
 svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
 .attr("d", valueline(data))
  .append("title");


 // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
.call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
.call(yAxis);

  // Y-axis labels
  svg.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "13px")
  .style("color", "#333333")
  .attr("transform", "translate ("+ (padding/4) + "," +(height/2)+")     rotate(-90)")
   .text("Tax Revenue")
   .style("font-family", "Arial"); 

  // X-axis labels
  svg.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "13px")
  .style("color", "#333333")
  . attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/2) + "," +(height-(padding/4)) + ")")
   .text("Fiscal Year")
   .style("font-family", "Arial"); 

  //source

   svg.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "13px")
  .style("color", "#333333")
 .attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/4.5) + "," +(height/1) + ")")
 .text("Source: DC OCFO")
 .style("font-family", "Arial")

   //title for the chart 

  svg.append("text")
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 .style("font-size", "16px")
  .style("color", "#333333")
 .attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/3) + "," +(height/30) + ")")
 .text("DC Total Tax Revenues by Fiscal Year")
  .style("font-family", "Arial");


  svg.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "left")
  .style("font-size", "13px")
  .style("color", "#333333")
 .attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/20) + "," +(height/12) + ")")
 .text("2000 to 2015")
 .style("font-family", "Arial")






 //line labels

   svg.append('g')
 .classed('labels-group', true)
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
   .enter()

  .append('text')
  .filter(function(d, i) { return i === 0||i === (data.length - 1) })
  .classed('label',true)

  .classed('label',true)
  .attr({
   'x':function(d,i) {
    return x(d.Date);

   },
  'y':function(d,i) {
    return y(d["Tax Collections"]);
  }
  })
  .text(function(d,i){
  return "$" + d["Tax Collections"] + "B";
 })
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")") 



 });

 </script>
 </body>
```

[image: This is the line chart]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This link may be helpful - http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While rendering your line labels, you just want to add an event listener for mouseover that shows and hides it. So it appears everything here is good to go except for showing and hiding your labels, which again you should do on mouseover/mouseout.

Here's an example of what I mean that I recently worked on:

```
g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('cx', function(){ return x(j.timestamp._d); })
    .attr('cy', function(){ return y(j.value); })
    .attr('r', 4)
    .attr('stroke', ML.colors.array[i])
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('fill', '#ffffff')
    .attr('class', 'circle-markers')
    .attr('data-index', k)
    .on('mouseover', function(){
            $(this).attr('fill', ML.colors.array[i]);
    }).on('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).attr('fill', '#ffffff');
    });
```

In this example I have a line chart with circles drawn at each point. The circles  initially have a white center with a stroke but on mouseover the center fills in the same color as the stroke. Then of course on mouseout this reverses.

Hope this helps.